# Not able to click on a button in a new window

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I trigger a click on a button which then opens another window (which is neither a new browser nor a frame).

In the new window I wish to click a button but my code is not triggering the click.

I tried to switch to keyword matching but it is still not working.

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Continue to General Information']")).click();
```

…which I am sure is not correct to click the button in the new window.

What syntax should I use to click the button?

Comment: Please could you also include an example of the HTML in both windows?

Comment: HTML of new Window:
<div id="d0EAAA5EBAC404A9A8493FF706DAD7E6D34_1" class="g-btn g-standard ">
<a id="d0EAAA5EBAC404A9A8493FF706DAD7E6D34_1_anchorId" onclick="DCT.Util.customOnClick(this);DCT.Util.processInterviewButtonAnchor('a_d0EAAA5EBAC404A9A8493FF706DAD7E6D34_1_div');" onfocus="" href="javascript:;" name="" onmouseout="window.status='';" onmousemove="window.status='';">
<div class="g-btn-l"/>
<div class="g-btn-m">
<span class="g-btn-text" data-tip="" ext:qtip="">Continue to General Information</span>
</div>
<div class="g-btn-r"/>

Comment: I am not able to add screen shot. If I could add, that will help to resolve the issue. Can you please help me in adding screen shot. 

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am able to identify object using xpath //span[text()='Continue to General Information'] but not clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

I found it [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/how-can-i-switch-to-new-window-using-webdriver). There is bit of an explanation of how it works there.

Comment: Thank you for your response but above code is not working. I am still not able to click on the link in new window.

Comment: Looking up at your HTML for the objects it seems extremly complicated. I'm not sure how you could navigate that to click. Go ahead and Inspect the element on add a comment here on Stack Overflow. I usually target a single input or a tag to click on, Never the entirety of the element that makes up that tag.